# Retrieve data from database without using extra page

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

In my 'django' project, I need to retrieve / insert data from multiple tables of my (mysql)database. However because of the code I used, I had to use an extra .html page for each table operation. I want to be able to access multiple tables on a single html page. In order to better explain the situation, I write the relevant codes of the project below.

*Project/views.py*

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    return render(request, "home.html", {})


@login_required()
def admin_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    return render(request, "adminPage.html", {})


@login_required()
def doctor_view(request):
    return render(request, 'doctorPage.html', {'doctors': doctor_view()})
```

*appointments/views.py*

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView


class list_of_appointments(ListView):

    model = Appointment
    template_name = 'appointments/appointment_list.html'


class list_of_patients(ListView):

    model = Patient
    template_name = 'appointments/patient_list.html'
```

*appointments/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^appointment_list/$', list_of_appointments.as_view(), name='list1'),
    url(r'^patient_list/$', list_of_patients.as_view(), name='list2')
]
```

So, in order to access the operations related to the tables, I have to use the following url code.

`<a href={% url 'appointments:list2' %}>`

Therefore, I can create a second html file and extract the data I want to extract from the database with this method.

```
 {% for appointment in object_list %}


        <tr>

            <td>{{ appointment.patient.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ appointment.doctor.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ appointment.Date }}</td>
            <td>{{ appointment.time }}</td>
            <td>{{ appointment.province }}</td>
            <td><a href="#">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
                                                                    aria-hidden="true"></span>Edit
                </button>
            </a></td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

But I want to do this database interaction on an existing html link (eg adminPage) without going to another link. Nowhere could I find out how to do this, can you help me? Thank you all!

Comment: probably, you need [jquery's ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [vanilla js's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)? with this things you can update any HTML element without reloading page.

Comment: Prob, you're right. But main issue of mine is 
'class list_of_patients(ListView)'

In this class, i can't match the template name to an existing template. (like adminPage.html) Because of that, i can't get data to my adminPage. Do you have any idea about this? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I reread question, and what I figgured out about a question: you want to use multiple models in same view, using `ListView`, right?

Comment: Kinda... I have pre-created page called as 'adminPage.' It's linked with my main project folder's urls.py and views.py. And I want to pull data from the database, to this page. Exactly "this page." I use ListView to retrieve data. However, i can't use ListView model with 'adminPage.' Whenever i write 'template_name= project/adminPage.html', I cannot retrieve data via database, I get a blank page.

But in the end, yes, i need to multiple models in same view page using ListView. But in the original problem, I can't use ListView on a previously created page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass more than one model to `ListView`, you can override `get_context_data` method of `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`. But be carefull, it should be a `QuerySet` object. The example look like this:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import FirstModel, SecondModel, ThirdModel

class MyListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'my_app/what-ever.html'
    model = Article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_first_model'] = FirstModel.objects.all()
        context['my_second_model'] = SecondModel.objects.all()
        context['my_third_model'] = ThirdModel.objects.all()
        return context
```

**what-ever.html**

```
{% for object in my_first_model %}
    <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ object.pk }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).